The functor $Sob \to Loc $ is faithful
I want to show that the functor $O: Sob \to  Loc$ from the sober topological spaces to the locales is faithful. So take $X,Y$ two sober topological spaces. I want to show that the map
$$O_{X,Y}: Hom(X,Y)\to Hom(O(Y),O(X))$$ is injective,
where $O(X)$ is the set of open sets of $X$.
So let $f,g:X\to Y$ two continuous masp such that $O_{X,Y}(f)=O_{X,Y}(g)$. So for all open set $U$ of $Y$ we have $f^{-1}(U)=g^{-1}(U)$.
Is this enough to say that $f=g$?

No, it's not enough yet. To get from "for all open $U$, $f^{1-}(U)=g^{1-}(U)$ to "$f=g$" is just a restatement of the original problem.  The solution will have to use the assumption that the spaces are sober.
